# Growth rate of Mellin transform

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, contour-integration, gamma-function, mellin-transform

For $x>0$ and $0<\sigma <1/6$ consider $$\int _{\sigma \pm i\infty }\underbrace {\frac {\Gamma ^3(s/2)}{\Gamma ^3((1-s)/2)}}_{=:G}\frac {ds}{x^s}$$
which is absolutely convergent since $G\asymp |t|^{3\sigma -3/2}$ for large $|t|$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.  In https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/sieve-methods-exponential-sums-and-their-applications-in-number-theory/on-the-ternary-additive-divisor-problem-and-the-sixth-moment-of-the-zetafunction/DBEDC56531F9A6C7466D0018DB10CC31 the author states (equation (3.17) and definition (3.7)) that with a trivial estimation the above integral is $\ll x^\epsilon $.  My question is **why is this true?**

What I know/understand: For $|t|\geq 1$ we have the above bound for $G$, whilst for $|t|\leq 1$ we have $G\asymp 1/|s|^3$ so if $x\gg 1$ then we can just choose say $\epsilon =1/10$ to see that the integral is $$\ll x^{-1/10}\int _{1/10\pm i}\frac {ds}{|s|^3}+\int _{1/10+i}^{1/10+i\infty }t^{3/10-3/2}dt\ll 1\ll x^\epsilon $$ so I'm ok in that case.  My issue is with small $x$, where the claimed bound is stronger than $\ll 1$.  (Also - the author really does wants arbitrarily small $x$, so it's not "he probably means $x>x_0$" or something).

I think for small $x$ I could choose $\epsilon =1/|\log x|$ so that $1/x^\epsilon =e$ so that the part of the integral with $|t|\geq 1$ is again $\ll 1$ leaving me with just the part $$\int _{1/\log x\pm i}\frac {Gds}{x^s}$$ left to bound.  But now I'm obviously doing something wrong because if I deform this path into a half-circle to the left of zero, then the integrand will be $\ll 1/x^{-1}+1/x^\epsilon \ll 1$ which is fine, but I'd've picked a residue at $s=0$ which gives the true size of the integral to be $Res_{s=0}G/x^s\approx (\log x)^2$, which contradicts the claim.  (I also think the author would have mentioned the argument if it involved deforming the integral, so I'm assuming there's something easier I'm missing.)

What am I not doing correctly or misunderstanding?

Comment: my issue is with $x\rightarrow 0$.  i've not understood your comment on how the integrand oscillation may affect what happens in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial estimate is

$$|\int _{\Re(s)=\sigma }\frac {\Gamma ^3(s/2)}{\Gamma ^3((1-s)/2)}\frac {ds}{x^s}|\le x^{-\sigma}\int_{\Re(s)=\sigma }|\frac {\Gamma ^3(s/2)}{\Gamma ^3((1-s)/2)}| d|s| =O(x^{-\sigma})$$
To improve it as $x\to 0$ shift the integral to the left
$$\int_{\Re(s)=\sigma }\frac {\Gamma ^3(s/2)}{\Gamma ^3((1-s)/2)}\frac {ds}{x^s}$$ $$=\int_{\Re(s)=-1/2}\frac {\Gamma ^3(s/2)}{\Gamma ^3((1-s)/2)}\frac {ds}{x^s}  + 2i\pi Res(\frac {\Gamma ^3(s/2)}{\Gamma ^3((1-s)/2)}x^{-s},0)$$
$$ = O(x^{1/2})+4 \pi^{-3/2}\log^2 x+O(\log x)$$
in particular it is not true that the integral is $O(x^\epsilon)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: my problem range is small $x$, where the claimed bound for the integral is stronger than $\ll 1$.  your bound is the same as the one i gave in my question, namely $\ll (\log x)^2$.  this is worse than $\ll 1$.

Comment: I didn't compute the residue but it is clearly the asymptotic as $x\to 0$, so your $O(x^\epsilon)$ claim is basically wrong @tomos

Comment: so the claim is wrong right?  do you think it's possible he meant $x^{-\epsilon }+1$?

Comment: The asymptotic as $x\to 0$ is the residue which is $\sim 4 \log^2(x)/\pi^{3/2}$ according to [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Res%5B+Gamma%28s%2F2%29%5E3+%2F+Gamma%28%281-s%29%2F2%29%5E3+*+x%5E%28-s%29%2C%7Bs%2C0%7D%5D)

Comment: (ah right i missed in your original answer that you say the claim is incorrect) thanks!